# Is there a way to span one app over more than one space?

Tags: macos, display, catalina, spaces

I'm using Citrix receiver with only one (laptop) display.

I figured out that if I would be able to span this application over (for example) three different spaces it would be a lot easier for me to work through Remote Desktop. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  Why would an application that is purportedly spanned over multiple spaces be easier to use via Remote Desktop?  You only view/use one space at a time, just like your screen.

Comment: My idea was to span Remote Desktop application on two or more spaces. Wider app window would let me keep more apps runned at one screen and switch between spaces would be like switching between apps inside Remote Desktop session